# acts_as_taggable_on how to use taggings_count with condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

i'm using https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on , within rails 5.2.3

My database

Blog(id: integer, admin_id: integer, title: string, description: text, status: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, tag_list: )

Tag(id: integer, name: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, taggings_count: integer)

Each update or create blog, i just want to count [taggings_count] if Blog.status = 2

i've tried but it not working

```
@blog.tag_counts_on(:context, { conditions: "blogs.status IS 2" })
```

Comment: Try `@blog.tag_counts_on(:context, { conditions: "blogs.status = 2" })`

Comment: thank you for reply, but it still not working

Comment: Does it give any error or just silence?

Comment: it just update(it mean count+1), don't give any error

Comment: can i use callback(exp: before_save) for ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag ?

Comment: what does `@blog.tag_counts_on(:context, { conditions: "blogs.status = 2" }).to_sql` output?

Comment: nothing happen. i think we should change solution to use callback